# error: create bucket err: -1 database public attribute invalid

Tags: database, time-series, window, cnosdb

I am in the window environment, building a single-node cnosdb.

```
cnosdb run -M singleton
```

and I create table and insert data ,

```
create table t1(f1 bigint, tags(t1));
insert into t1(time, t1, f1)values(now(), 't1', 2);
```

client report some error message

```
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"050001","error_message":"Meta request error: Request meta cluster error: create bucket err: -1 database public attribute invalid!"}
```

I write data repeatedly and find that occasional writes are successful.

and I check the log,there are some error message:

```
2023-08-04T18:35:33.648573600+08:00 ERROR meta::model::meta_admin: Failed to get disk info: (os error 123)
```